# Using javascript and regex to limit replacement and capture within a specific html tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm  using javascript and regular expression to convert this html code:

```
  <html>
        <body>
              <document>
                     ==id:firstid;
                     ==href:#anchor32145;
                     ==href:#anchor31274;
                     ==href:#anchor98751;
              </document>
              <document>
                     ==id:secondid;
                     ==href:#anchor62341;
              </document>
              <document>
                     ==id:thirdid;
                     ==href:#achor52153;
                     ==href:#anchor98421;
              </document>
        </body>
  </html>
```

into this format:

```
  <html>
        <body>
              <document>
                     ==id:firstid;
                     ==href: firstid #anchor32145;
                     ==href: firstid #anchor31274;
                     ==href: firstid #anchor98751;
              </document>
              <document>
                     ==id:secondid;
                     ==href: secondid #anchor62341;
              </document>
              <document>
                     ==id:thirdid;
                     ==href: thirdid #anchor52153;
                     ==href: thirdid #anchor98421;
              </document>
        </body>
  </html>
```

as you can see, what I'm trying to do is distribute the value of ==id: to all =href: within the same document tag. I'm relatively new to javascript, so any help to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are saner ways of doing this other than straight regex (an XML parser for example),
but since you asked for it ...

```js
const str =
  `  <html>
        <body>
              <document>
                     ==id:firstid;
                     ==href:#anchor32145;
                     ==href:#anchor31274;
                     ==href:#anchor98751;
              </document>
              <document>
                     ==id:secondid;
                     ==href:#anchor62341;
              </document>
              <document>
                     ==id:thirdid;
                     ==href:#achor52153;
                     ==href:#anchor98421;
              </document>
        </body>
  </html>`

const str2 = str.replace(/(?:<document>)[\s=\w]*:(\w*);[a-z0-9;:#\s=]*/g, (m, m1, m2) =>
  m.replace(/==href:/g, (mm) => ` ${mm} ${m1} `))
console.log(str2)
```